# Getting local network details with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need the local network details of the visitor. Preferably I'd retrieve them automatically as much as possible.
Specifically, the details I need are:

- Connection type (wifi/wired or 4g)
- Local IP
- Subnet mask
- default gateway

I've found the "effectiveType" in "navigator.connection", but this appears to be a estimate (based on downlink speed?) since it labels my current connection as "4g" while it should be WiFi.

http://net.ipcalf.com/ demonstrates a seemingly reliable way to retrieve the local IP.

Is there any way to retrieve the other details?

Alternatively I can have users enter them manually or ask them to download a detection.exe, but I'd rather keep it simple.

Comment: "wifi/wired or 4g" — These are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: i don't think this is possible. i'm surpised the ipcalf method works.

Comment: "*I need the local network details of the visitor*" - a normal website doesn't, and isn't allowed to for privacy reasons. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bergi I'd like to offer them to configure certain network components they order in my webshop.